# How to show user location along with custom annotations in MKMapView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, core-location

I'm showing some custom annotations in the mapview using below code,

```
for(int i=0;i<[[st.defaultmaparray objectAtIndex:0] count];i++)
{
 CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
 location.latitude = [[[st.defaultmaparray objectAtIndex:13] objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
 location.longitude = [[[st.defaultmaparray objectAtIndex:14] objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
 MKCoordinateRegion region;
 MKCoordinateSpan span;

 span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
 span.longitudeDelta = 0.05;

 region.span = span;
 region.center = location;
 [latlongarray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",location.latitude,location.longitude]];
 [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
 DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];

 ann.title = [[st.defaultmaparray objectAtIndex:3] objectAtIndex:i];
 ann.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",[[st.defaultmaparray objectAtIndex:4] objectAtIndex:i],[[st.defaultmaparray objectAtIndex:9] objectAtIndex:i],[[st.defaultmaparray objectAtIndex:10] objectAtIndex:i]];
 ann.coordinate = region.center;


 [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
   //[self.mapView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
}
```

and its viewforannotation method is as follows,

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
int imageint = [latlongarray indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",annotation.coordinate.latitude,annotation.coordinate.longitude]];
static NSString *SFAnnotationIdentifier = @"SFAnnotationIdentifier";
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
{
     NSLog(@" view for UL ");
     return nil;
}
else
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                          initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
    customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

    AsyncImageView *async = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    [async loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[st.defaultmaparray objectAtIndex:5] objectAtIndex:imageint]]];
    async.backgroundColor=[UIColor whitecolor];
    [sfIconView addSubview:async];
    sfIconView.frame = CGRectMake(-15, 0, 50, 50);
    [customPinView addSubview:async];
    return customPinView;
}
 return nil;
}
```

The above code works fine and the output is like below,

[image]

But, now I need to show the user's current location along with these custom annotations. The user's location should be shown like the blue dot marker with circular wave around it like below image,

[image]

How to add that? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show user location add this:

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

If you are running your app on simulator, please add custom location by entering latitude and longitude
**Select iOS Simulator -> Debug -> Location -> CustomLocation**

Comment: This simple thing that I missed, Thanks for remembering.